# How is div height calculated from font size

Tags: html, css

Is there is a way to calculate automatic `div` height knowing contained font size and family? How does browser calculate this? Example:

```
<div style="font-size: 14px; font-family: courier">Text</div>
```

Above `div` height will be 16px; for `"font-family: times"` it will be 17px.

Comment: You just want to get the height? Or you want the div to be 14px also?

Comment: @HermLuna I'd like to calculate this, without accessing DOM.

Comment: I don't think css can get exact height. What will you do with it? Maybe, there's another way to do it w/o accessing DOM.

Comment: I think @Samir's comment on their answer explains it best with the `div` defaulting to auto size from its content. It's a little unclear what you're asking, though. Are you looking to use the height of the `div` to size other elements? Are you looking to perform a calculation on this? There are suggestions using JS/jQuery, which is a good way to use the size of the `div`, but I'm not sure what you're looking to do with the measurement when you've got it. Can you clarify in your question, please?

Comment: @GeoffJames I need to add some overlay to a div, and I need to know exact height. I'm in GWT, and `Element.getClientHeight()` is heavy. I see there's no simple answer, so the best I can do – get client height once and cache it per font.

Comment: @AlexeyBerezkin - so, do you need the overlay to cover just the div that contains the text? That's just a case of using the `div` with text as a parent, and inserting another (empty) `div` inside of that with a CSS class to manipulate the color/size etc. Then make the parent div have `position: relative` and the child (overlay div) `position: absolute` and `top: 0; left: 0;` with a `height` and `width` of `100%`  (or `right` and `bottom` set to `0`, also). I might be clutching at straws with that, but if that is the case, I would have included what your intended outcome was in your question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer to your question is that it isn't straightforward.

For proportional fonts, the line height is either

- the value of the `line-height` property if it's set in absolute lengths.
  `<div style="line-height:20px">Text</div>` will be 20px high
- or the value of the `line-height` property multiplied by the `font-size` property if the `line-height` is a unitless value.
  `<div style="line-height:1.5; font-size:14px">Text</div>` will be 21px high
- or some value chosen by the browser if `line-height` is set to its default value of `normal`.
  `<div style="font-size: 14px;">Text</div>` will usually be around 17px high, but this may vary among browsers and/or fonts

With monospace fonts however, like "Courier" in your example, the calculation depends on the browser and the browser settings.
Many browsers use a smaller size than the `font-size` for monospace fonts. This is a historical convention. How much smaller exactly, the convention doesn't say.
So with monospace fonts, all bets are off. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the height of the `div`, prior to the font or something else.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     var outerHeight = $('div').outerHeight();
     alert(outerHeight);

});
```

[Refer here](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)

Comment: I'd like to calculate div height without accessing DOM.

Comment: Since `div` is a `block level` element. Hence it will take `100%` width and it will take the height with respect to the content inside it. Without accessing any DOM how can you get the height? Either CSS or JS, you have to refer to the DOM. With out that referring height How can you determine which element height you need.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the height of the container is determined by `line-height`, which is calculated automatically and may differ using different fonts.
You can force the height explicitly setting the line-height in CSS.

In this fiddle I set the first two divs' line-heights at 20px, while in the third it is calculated by the browser: https://jsfiddle.net/wvp476cL/1/

You can get (and set) an element height using javascript.