# How does height will be calculated, based on font-size?

Tags: css

When you write this: (in chrome)

```html
<div style="font-size: 32px">txt</div>
```

its height will be 37px.
but this one:

```html
<div style="font-size: 16px">txt</div>
```

its height will be 18px.

So my question is: is there any formula to calculate how much will be a text's height  when rendered (based on font-size)?

Comment: Depends of the browser. I'm using chrome too and i get different results on your examples (16px, height is 18.8px). Of you course you can control that by setting `line-height`

Comment: @VilleKoo perhaps because your browser default font family is different than me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The height is not based on the `font-size` but the `line-height` and the default value is `normal`

> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of **roughly 1.2**, depending on the element's font-family.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values)</sup>

Basically, we don't know exactly the value of `line-height` but if we explicitely define it then we can know the exact height.

An example where I am setting the height to be `1.5 x font-size`

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).height());
})
```

```css
div {
  line-height:1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 32px">txt</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px">txt</div>
```

Another one where the height is `35px` for all of them:

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).height());
})
```

```css
div {
  line-height:35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 32px">txt</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px">txt</div>
```

---

Worth to note that the result is different if you consider an inline element:

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  console.log("div "+$(this).height());
})
$('span').each(function(){
  console.log("span "+$(this).height());
})
```

```css
div,span {
  line-height:1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 32px">txt</div>
<div style="font-size: 16px">txt</div>

<span style="font-size: 32px">txt</span>
<span style="font-size: 16px">txt</span>
```

Or if you have different `font-size` inside a div or different alignment:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  console.log("div " + $(this).height());
})
```

```css
div {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span style="font-size: 32px">txt</span>
  <span style="font-size: 16px">txt</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span style="font-size: 32px;vertical-align:text-top">txt</span>
  <span style="font-size: 32px">txt</span>
</div>
```

In the first case, the height will be defined only based on the font properties (line-height play no role here).

> the height of the content area should be based on the font <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)</sup>
>
> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

In the second case, we have a more *realistic* example where the height is not only based on the `line-height` but also consider the alignment of the different elements to find the final height we need in order to place all of them.

More details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

Comment: thanks for answer. someone suggested a dupicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869510/how-is-div-height-calculated-from-font-size should i accept it?

Comment: @yaya yes, it seems the same question but I am trying to add more details to mine to make it a bit different