# Some line-height values on inline elements results in strange container heights

Tags: html, css, typography, line-height

Consider the following code (an inline <span> contained within a block-level <div>):

```
<div>
    <span style="font-size:40px;line-height:3px;">HELLO</span>
</div>
```

This will result in the <div> having a height of 19px. How did the browser arrive at this value of 19px?

The following snippet is that code in action:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="font-family:'Arial';">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Line-Height Test</title>
</head>
<body style="padding-top:50px;padding-right:calc(100% - 300px);">
<div id="greenDiv" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    <span style="font-size:40px;line-height:3px;">HELLO</span>
</div>
<div id="infoDiv" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
<script>
    (() => {
        const infoDiv = document.getElementById("infoDiv");
        const greenDiv = document.getElementById("greenDiv");
        let html = `The inner &lt;span&gt; is ${greenDiv.firstElementChild.offsetHeight}px tall,`;
        html += ` but its container (the outer green &lt;div&gt;) is only ${greenDiv.offsetHeight}px tall.`;
        html += `<br/>How did the browser arrive at this ${greenDiv.offsetHeight}px value?`;
        infoDiv.innerHTML = html;
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove all styles from the span, the div is still 23px tall. It seems that's its natural height for this particular font and default line height.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand, make the `line-height` equal to `0` and you will get a height equal to `18px` for the div. The div has the default `font-size` equal to `16px` and the default `line-height` is equal to `normal`. The `normal` value is based on the font and in this case it seems to be equal to `1.125` to have `18px = 1.125 * 16px`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="font-family:'Arial';">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Line-Height Test</title>
</head>
<body style="padding-top:50px;padding-right:calc(100% - 300px);">
<div id="greenDiv" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    <span style="font-size:40px;line-height:0;">HELLO</span>
</div>
<div id="infoDiv" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
<script>
    (() => {
        const infoDiv = document.getElementById("infoDiv");
        const greenDiv = document.getElementById("greenDiv");
        let html = `The inner &lt;span&gt; is ${greenDiv.firstElementChild.offsetHeight}px tall,`;
        html += ` but its container (the outer green &lt;div&gt;) is only ${greenDiv.offsetHeight}px tall.`;
        html += `<br/>How did the browser arrive at this ${greenDiv.offsetHeight}px value?`;
        infoDiv.innerHTML = html;
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if you start increasing the `line-height` of the span, the height of the div will increase due to the vertical alignment. This is a bit tricky because we need some complex calculation to identify the final height but if you change the alignment of the span to something different from `baseline` (the default one), the height will get back to `18px` whataver the `line-height`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="font-family:'Arial';">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Line-Height Test</title>
</head>
<body style="padding-top:50px;padding-right:calc(100% - 300px);">
<div id="greenDiv" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
    <span style="font-size:40px;line-height:18px;vertical-align: top">HELLO</span>
</div>
<div id="infoDiv" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
<script>
    (() => {
        const infoDiv = document.getElementById("infoDiv");
        const greenDiv = document.getElementById("greenDiv");
        let html = `The inner &lt;span&gt; is ${greenDiv.firstElementChild.offsetHeight}px tall,`;
        html += ` but its container (the outer green &lt;div&gt;) is only ${greenDiv.offsetHeight}px tall.`;
        html += `<br/>How did the browser arrive at this ${greenDiv.offsetHeight}px value?`;
        infoDiv.innerHTML = html;
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using `line-height: 18px` with a top alignment and the total height is still `18px`. If I increase the `line-height` of the span, the height will also increase. If you update the alignment the height will also increase.

To conclude, the `line-height` and `font-size` of the div will set a minimum height. This minimum height can be changed by the `line-height` of the inner element and their vertical alignment.

Related questions:

[How does height will be calculated, based on font-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58166120/8620333)

[Why inline and inline-block have different height with the same text content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65386958/8620333)

[How to determine height of content-box of a block and inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61830546/8620333)